# How to do this sql query for aggregating counts in a one-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, lists and globals_lists. A globals_lists basically associates a list_id with a global_id value. I'd like to get a count of global_ids (ie the number of 'manys' in the globals_lists table) for the associated list type for each user.

something like:

```
select l.id, l.user_id, count(gl.global_id) as gl_count 
from   lists l, globals_lists gl 
where  l.list_type_id=10 and l.id=gl.list_id;
```

but this is giving me back wrong information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
GROUP BY l.id, l.user_id
```

after your `where` clause.

Without `GROUP BY`, you are basically just counting up all rows that meet the `WHERE` and join conditions without any regard to set grouping. `GROUP BY` will ensure that you are performing the count aggregation ***per*** user -> list combination.

Comment: thx, this gets the answer but it looks like specifying EITHER l.id or l.user_id will get the right answer. Should specifying either work ok?

Comment: @timpone It's best practice to specify all non-aggregating fields you are selecting in the `SELECT` clause in the `GROUP BY` clause as well. MySQL cuts you some slack on this via what it calls the "hidden columns extension", but other DBMSs will not be so forgiving. Also, what fields you want to group on depends on your design... it seems to me that you should be getting different results if you only grouped on either one of the fields...

Answer (score 1):

```
select l.id, l.user_id, count(gl.global_id) as gl_count 
from   lists l, globals_lists gl 
where  l.list_type_id=10 and l.id=gl.list_id
GROUP BY l.id, l.user_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use an aggregate function like `count`, you should specify the group on which the aggregate should operate.  MySQL does not require this, but it's always clearer if you do.

In your case, the group you're looking for is `(user_id, list_id)`.  You could write the query like:

```
select  l.user_id
,       l.id
,       count(gl.global_id) as gl_count 
from    lists l
join    globals_lists gl 
on      l.id = gl.list_id
where   l.list_type_id = 10
group by
        l.user_id
,       l.id
```